# Can I publish an app to EMM without it first being available publicly on Google Play store

Tags: android, mdm

I've got an internal corporate application that I need to have published in my company's Android for work EMM.

Do I need to first publish the application publicly on Google Play Store or is there a way to upload just to EMM. I'm really reluctant to publish publicly.

The app had not been published on Google Play so there's no problem with the apps package already being used.

Comment: Have you read this https://developers.google.com/android/work/overview#app_distribution and the pages it links to? The answer is likely in there

Answer (score 0):

The Play Developer Console allows you to restrict the visibility of your app to your enterprise by publishing your app as "private", see their very good [help center article](https://support.google.com/googleplay/work/answer/6145139).